# Nhibernate QueryOver Orderby

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I'm trying to decouple the orderby on a queryover call and this doesn't compile

```
protected static void AddOrder<T>(IQueryOver<T, T> criteria, Expression<Func<object>> expression )
{
  criteria.OrderBy(expression).Asc;
}
```

I'm guessing there is a way to do this, somehow bringing in the asc into the linq expression?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how IQueryOver works... to make it compile, you'd have to do the following:

```
protected static IQueryOver<T, T> AddOrder<T>(IQueryOver<T, T> criteria,
                                              Expression<Func<object>> expression)
{
    return criteria.OrderBy(expression).Asc;
}
```

Which makes little sense, as it's just a dumb wrapper for `OrderBy`.

Comment: Thanks. That's horrible :@ it makes no sense even when you understand how it works, not sure who thought of that design :@ Sometimes I hate NH