# NHibernate detached OrderBy

Tags: nhibernate, repository, queryover, detachedcriteria

I am using a repository pattern to wrap NHibernate entities.  One of the methods is `public IList<T> GetAll()` which simply returns all items of that entity.  The implementation is done in either Criteria or QueryOver.

I would like to overload this method to accept a sorting order, something like this: `public IList<T> GetAll(NHOrderFor<T> order)` which I could call and fluently define the order for.  Is this possible?  QueryOver is preferred but not required.

### Update

I got a little further ahead.  I defined the parameter as `Expression<Func<T,object>> path` which is what's expected by QueryOver.OrderBy() but the expression is missing the `.Asc or .Desc` specification that's required to follow.

Comment: yes. pass a Func<T> to it. then in your query session.GetAll().orderby(func);

Comment: Looks like this can't be done with QueryOver: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943777/nhibernate-queryover-orderby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in a bool variable to determine if it's asc or desc - the only "tricky" part is that the .Asc and .Desc are properties, so you have to assign them to a result (you don't need to do anything with the result tho - it just returns the same queryover), eg:

```
public IList<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T,object>> path, bool ascending) {
    if (ascending)
        queryOver = queryOver.OrderBy(path).Asc;
    else
        queryOver = queryOver.OrderBy(path).Desc;
    return queryOver.List<T>();
}
```